# Grub install failing trying to dual boot on XPS 13 (2015)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, dell

I just purchased a new Dell XPS 13 from the Microsoft Store and installed Ubuntu on it.  It seemed to work fine with a few issues that appeared to be resolvable with the last bios update.  I performed the bios update which prevented my Ubuntu partition from booting.

Attempting to re-install, I get the following error message... "The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' packed failed to install into /target/.  Without the GRUB boot loader, the installed system will not boot"

I can't seem to find much information on resolving this and after lots of searching, I can't seem to find any sort of reason as to why the grub bootloader won't install.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [16.04 new installation gives grub-efi-amd64-signed failed installation /target/ ubuntu 16.04 at the end](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789998/16-04-new-installation-gives-grub-efi-amd64-signed-failed-installation-target)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Dell XPS 13 (9343 model) from work, and first thing I did was wipe the disk, and install Ubuntu 14.04. I'm running the latest BIOS, A03.

I did alot of tinkering to get the laptop booting. I discovered that the laptop will not work with UEFI booting. You need to disable secureboot, and boot the install media as a legacy device. Then perform a usual installation.

Once you have installed Ubuntu, check what kernels you have available. For me, I had to boot the 3.16.0-30-generic kernel, as the 0.16.0-36-generic booted to a black screen.

You can either edit the grub configs yourself, or choose to install "Grub customizer" (https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer) to fix which version you boot.

Bonus info: I also had trouble with the touchpad (not able to click and hold, and right click was messed up), and letters going missing on the screen. I fixed touchpad by telling synaptics it's a clickpad, and I fixed the missing letters by setting intel to "uxa" accellation mode (slower, but works). Edit/add the xorg.conf file, and put the following in it:

/etc/xorg.conf

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad"
    Driver "synaptics"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        Option "ClickPad" "true"
EndSection

Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "AccelMethod"  "uxa"
EndSection
```

If you use sleep (ex. lid close/open) then you may encounter that touchpad is not working when the computer wakes up. To fix this add this file to /etc/pm/sleep.d/

20_fix-drivers-after-sleep

```
case "${1}" in
    resume|thaw)
    modprobe -r i2c_hid
    modprobe i2c_hid
;;
esac
```

I got most of my help from this helpful blog post and various other sites i cannot recall... http://forthescience.org/blog/2015/03/20/installing_ubuntu_14_04_on_the_new_dell_xps_13/