# Error grub-efi-amd64-signed failed to install into /target/

Tags: boot, uefi, 64-bit

After installing Ubuntu 16.04 on a HP stream netbook, I got this

```
Error: grub-efi-amd64-signed failed to install into /target/
```

I have tried all sorts of different fixes:

- legacy mode on/off
- secure boot on/off
- running the install again choosing my own partition because of UEFI specs.

I can't even remember all the things I've tried I'm just exhausted and annoyed at this. Please help.

Comment: May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/   Looks like a real lightweight system, are you installing a Lightweight flavor of Ubuntu? Lightweight flavors
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu mate, Budgie
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors

Comment: Thanks for replying I ran boot repair and got Error:/var/log/boot-repair/20171017_180945/sda/current_mbr.img does not exist

Comment: Fyi I tried both Ubuntu and Lubuntu got the same issue with both.

Comment: Did you boot in UEFI mode? Boot-Repair trys to back up MBR for BIOS installs as a just in case, but with UEFI, MBR should be empty.

Comment: Should I try it in legacy or UEFI mode? I'm just confused as fuck at this point..

Comment: I have tried all the options and get the same error with mbr does not exist message

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/789998/16-04-new-installation-gives-grub-efi-amd64-signed-failed-installation-target  .  Please post the link to the boot-repair link so we can see what might be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Just to reply to you I've created this account and it's my first ever reply
Even I was facing the same issue from past 3 days.

Now I've successfully installed Ubuntu 17.10. I'll tell the process as short as possible.

1. Enable legacy.
2. When you boot up the OS live, click on install and reach to the process where you select the partition. Here instead of giving 2 partition (i.e swap & ext4), we'll give 3 partitions(ext4, swap and efi).
3. Now you give ext4 partition with `/` mount point.
4. Select how much swap you want as well.
5. Now, select more than 1 GB (I took 2GB) and give the partition as efi.
6. Now carry on the remaining installation.

You'll be able to install the OS.
Remove USB when reboot and Enjoy :)