# Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10 not booting after dual boot installation

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, 18.04

I tried to install Ubuntu 18.04 as a second OS, but now neither of them is booting anymore. While boot "System BootOrder not found. Initializing defaults. Boot System." is displayed. See the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot: Boot Error]
<sup>**Boot error**</sup>

I followed [this guide](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Dualboot/) and created two (/ and /home) partitions like in the screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot: Partitions]
<sup>**Partitions**</sup>

Beause it did not work and displayed this:

```
grub-efi-amd64-signed failed installation /target/
```

I found [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789998/16-04-new-installation-gives-grub-efi-amd64-signed-failed-installation-target) to create a third FAT32 boot/esp partition to successfully install grub and Ubuntu, but now I can't boot either of them.

#### Some more screenshots:

[image: Screenshot: Boot menu]
<sup>**Boot menu**</sup>

[image: Screenshot: UEFI boot settings]
<sup>**UEFI boot settings**</sup>

Did I mess with the bootloader/MBR, and why did I need to create the esp/boot partition to install grub?

Additional information:

[Secure boot configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPq6G.jpg)

Comment: It might help to have some additional information:
Do you have Sceure Boot enabled or disabled?
If you have, could you use a boot cdrom / USB stick and try if the file systems on the hdd are still in a valid state?
Is the first (small) partition on the nvme (p1) a rescue system or does this solve other purposes, like an UEFI partition already?

Comment: @pdr Which information should I provide?

Comment: sorry, hit the enter key too fast, edited original comment.

Comment: @pdr Secure Boot is disabled. I added the screenshot at the end of my question. Right now I am running ubuntu from a live usb device. I can see all the data on my windows 10 partitions, so it seems like they are in a valid state. I don't exactly know the purpose of nvme (p1). I just know windows 10 installation created it automatically while installation. Only p2 and p3 where created by hand while windows 10 installation.

Comment: - Thank you. To be precise, the screen shot doesn't show anything obvious about secure boot, just UEFI which isn't the same ;)
I assume, you gave it a try switching off Legacy Boot and CSM support?

Comment: @pdr Yes, I tried switching off Legacy Boot and CSM support. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76650/discussion-between-pdr-and-helloworld0815).