# the 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into /target/

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi, error-handling

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 but I get this error at the end of installation process!

I tried to create a partition with `ext4` for `\boot`. also `ext1` but non of them worked. Also I tried to choose the `ntfs` partition that my Windows 10 grub file is in that but didn't work too.

I also had Ubuntu 16.04 beside my Windows 10 on this Laptop, But when I tried to format the old Linux and install the new one, I get this error message!

(My Windows is installed on sda (Samsung ssd hard))

Edit: Screen shot didn't work and couldn't large the window to show off all the partitions, so I took 2 images:

[image]
[image]

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/789998/16-04-new-installation-gives-grub-efi-amd64-signed-failed-installation-target  You have not followed the instructions for installing uefi. See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Creating_an_EFI_System_Partition  "\boot" is NOT correct. It needs to be "/boot/efi".

Comment: @Rinzwind: I read the link you put but couldn't exactly understand what it means? In the link it says if you have installed windows there is no need to create a EFI partition. But I tried it and didn't work

Comment: No. It says: if you already have a windows using efi...Because there should only 1 efi. Basically you need to create a /boot/efi partition of roughly 100Mb-500Mb unless you already have  a /boot/efi from another operating system.  And I do not see an efi label in your partition list.... so that is a legacy windows.

Comment: @Rinzwind: I had Windows10 beside the ubuntu 16.04. I though maybe I had it before. So you say what should I do? I must delete sdb5 to sdb8 partitions, and first create a sdb5 with 300MB and EFI format, then create other ext4 and swap partitions again?

Comment: Why not use sdb8? Format to fat32 and mount as /boot/efi ? It does not need to be the 1st partition (legacy did need that).

Comment: @Rinzwind: Is this a bad idea to change the sda1 format? I think it's made by windows10 when I installed

Comment: I created a new 500MB partion on sdb8 and changed to use as FAT32 filesystem. But in Mount point, it has only 2 options : `/dos` `/windows`