# "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message

Tags: boot, system-installation, kernel, xorg, proc

I was trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 here: [the 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into /target/](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041532/the-grub-efi-amd64-signed-package-failed-to-install-into-target/1041537?noredirect=1#comment1696711_1041537)

Finally I created a new partition `sdb8 efi` and then Installed Linux successfully. But at the end of installation it asked me to restart and I accepted. But before it done, It gave me this messages as you can see completely on image:

> "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this
> message. info task xorg blocked xxx for more than 120 seconds

[image]

After a forced shutdown I got this error message when I started my PC again:

[image]

Comment: Hi, have you done dual booting?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this .... working ... open terminal and start typing

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Add the following line at the end of the file:

```
kernel.hung_task_timeout_secs = 0
```

Save the file and run the following command to apply the changes without rebooting:

```
sudo sysctl -p
```