# How too boot windows using only live ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot

Previously i had two OS (windows 10 and ubuntu 16.04) installed alongside in my computer. Recently i decided to install a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 over the old one, but i got several issues including problem [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789998/16-04-new-installation-gives-grub-efi-amd64-signed-failed-installation-target) and after i solved that i could install the ubuntu but after installation completed and asked me to restart i encountered with `ubuntu boot failed|` massage, finally i couldn't manage to fix this.
Now i only want to be able to boot windows and i only have a USB stick of the Ubuntu installion and nothing else.
I wanted to know can i boot into windows without installing Ubuntu (cause i can't Right now), using only Live ubuntu?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you. Are you saying you installed Ubuntu 18.04 and wiped out Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 in the process?

Comment: Windows 10 is not wiped out, it's still there as before. I just wiped ex4 partition of Ubuntu

Comment: First, you said you have a problem and gave a link called "here".  The link has a question with 14 answers... many comments, and of course the question.  You might have considered some type of specifics that you wanted us to look at.  So we don't know what your original issue was... it's to vague.  Glad you resolved it.  As far as your question about booting to Windows without an OS installed, that's not possible from Linux.  I don't think it's possible from Windows installers either.  You can boot the Ubuntu to live ubuntu and browse your windows partition... (continued)

Comment: ... (continued) However, you can't boot to the Ubuntu live media, then switch to the Windows OS.  You can't do that with the Ubuntu installer, and I don't think you can do that with the Windows Installer either.  You would have to install an OS, then have a multiple boot option of which OS to boot to.  We can assist you with issues with installing Ubuntu, that is what this site is about.  But you'll have to use one of our sister sites for other things which aren't Ubuntu related.  **A direct answer to your quesiton is... you can't**.  You can either run Ubunt (try Ubuntu) or install Ubuntu.

Comment: You can re-install Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, let it identify Windows and create a menuentry for it in the grub menu. Then you can make that the default boot option. See [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#Configuring_GRUB_2).