# Failed to install grub2 while installing ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I am getting error while installing Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in my laptop. I can not understand why such problem is happening. The error is:

```
'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into /target/. without the grub boot loader, the installed system will not boot.
```

Last week my laptop stop working and shutdown I tried all possible solution but iI couldn't start, then stared to install Ubuntu in my partition SDA6 (one of partitions) but at the end of installation process I got `grub-efi-amd64-signed package failed to install.`

Comment: Is it dual boot or Ubuntu alone?? You missed creating EFI Partition that's why you are getting that error. If it's Ubuntu alone. Create a EFI partition. ext4 / and then if you want /home and swap etc..

Comment: ubuntu alone, i have create EFI partition choosing ext4 from dropdown while installing,

Comment: is it a empty disk or do you have data on it? Go with "try Ubuntu" option. Open GParted and post the Pic to see further..

Comment: The ESP - efi system partition must be FAT32 with boot flag on gpt partitioned drives. Only if using BIOS boot on gpt drive, then you need a tiny 1 or 2MB unformatted partition with the bios_grub flag. If using gdisk, the ESP is code ef00 and bios_grub is ef02. Actual code inside gpt partition is a very long GUID for partition type. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [16.04 new installation gives grub-efi-amd64-signed failed installation /target/ ubuntu 16.04 at the end](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789998/16-04-new-installation-gives-grub-efi-amd64-signed-failed-installation-target)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to install Ubuntu in UEFI mode without setting up an EFI System Partition (ESP). You have to create this partition. Ideal size for it should be 100 MB.

Comment: I have created 90GB partition of ext4/ with 8GB  swap but when grup2 installing start it terminates with such error

Comment: Before creating those 2 partitions create EFI partition of 100mb

Comment: This error comes in the last of ubuntu installation process, After application,games,utility packages and user creation process when grub2 and bootloader start installing then such error occures

Comment: How do i create EFI partion of 100mb give me any link or content

Comment: same as ext4 and swap you will have EFI option from drop down menu.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue while installing `Ubuntu 18.04` in My brother's laptop! And I tried to reinstall again! But I got same error! I created 500 MB of `/boot`  partition! Then it solved the issue!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue still appears when I tried to install ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my HP laptop. I don't have dual boot. Previous on SSD I had Windows 7 OS.
I've spent hours of trying several options: connect/disconnect internet connection while installing, install 3rd/don't install 3rd parties, boot in secure mode/ don't boot in secure boot. During installation I've choose every time "Something else" ad go according to [ubuntu official guideline to set disks properly](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace).

I was so frustrated.

What finally worked? I set in BIOS "Legacy mode" instead of "UEFI". On (almost) every forum I read to "be sure you are booting in UEFI mode", and I don't know why but in my case it didn't worked at all.

I've choose "Legacy Mode" + used [ubuntu official guideline to set disks properly](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace).Using Legacy Mode we don't need to create /EFI disk, but /boot. Everything is described in attached link. After setting up your disk, you will be asked "there is no EFI partition which is needed/ it may couse fail in the future, are you sure?"- click OK.

It worked in my case - hope will also help you.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution (it just now worked for me):
Once the install fails, you should be taken to a website that attempts to help you. 
Immediately exit out of the browser when you see this page.
It will then take you to the “try out Ubuntu” version of the desktop of Ubuntu.
Choose to install Ubuntu, and then once you get to the install type choose “Erase Ubuntu  and reinstall”.
Just did it and it worked! You can also choose all of the other same options you’ve already been choosing.