# grub-efi-amd64-signed package failed to install into /target/ using ISO and UEFI mode

Tags: server, grub2, 18.04, grub-efi, pxe

I am installing **Ubuntu-18.04** using **PXE** ISO install in **UEFI** mode. The installation is failing with the below message:

[image: Error message]

I looked into this thread [grub-efi-amd64-signed failed installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789998/16-04-new-installation-gives-grub-efi-amd64-signed-failed-installation-target) but they are for manual installation. My query is for Unattended Installation over PXE server on client machine.

Please comment if I need to add more details to the question.

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair-ubuntu
```

- Search app "boot repair".
- Use the advance boot option.
- Finished.