# problems trying to dual boot lubuntu with windows 7

Tags: boot, dual-boot

i want to start the odin project and they recommend that you either

- have dedicated linux machine
- have a mac
- have dual boot if you want to keep windows

and they recommend lubuntu, xubuntu or ubuntu and i've choosed lubuntu and set aside 20gb since is just to code and learn everything they teach you i've made a live usb with unetbootin and all fine and dandy until now, it boots perfectly and i use gparted to make my partitions i go with 10 gb for root 2 gb for swap and the rest (8gb) for home and this is where my problems began

i have 3 main problems

1. at boot (try lubuntu) it display something like ''problem loading uefi db x.509 certificate (-22)'' three separate times (i've read that it's maybe due secure boot but it's disabled already)
2. when i get to choose the instalation type (where it's supposed to appear the ''install lubuntu alongside windows 7'') said option isn't there (dont know if it's really a problem because i use the ''something else'' option)
3. after i assign the mount points (/, swap, /home) and pick bootloader folder (/dev/sda) and click install now and when it's almost finnished an error pops out that goes like this '' The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into /target/. Without the GRUB boot loader, the installed system will not boot'' and it thows me back to the desktop
4. bonus problem: the partition that has my windows loader in it (/dev/sda1) that it's supposed to read ''windows 7 loader'' instead appears as ''unknown'' as well the partition that has my windows on it (/dev/sda2)
   i've been googling almost all day to no avail I have

   - safe boot dissabled and in standard mode
   - csm enabled
   - fast boot disabled (although i dont think that is the same w8 fast boot)
   - uefi enabled
   - legacy mode enabled
   - boot priority uefi first
   - have lubuntu 64 bits

im at a total lost here and i dont know what else to do if anyone can throw me a line here i would be deeply thankful for
and good job withstanding my wall of text! a winner is you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [16.04 new installation gives grub-efi-amd64-signed failed installation /target/ ubuntu 16.04 at the end](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789998/16-04-new-installation-gives-grub-efi-amd64-signed-failed-installation-target)

Comment: Win7 is usually installed in legacy mode. You should install Lubuntu in the same boot mode. How you boot is how you install, to install in legacy mode, boot in legacy mode.

Answer (score 0):

Boot up the live usb and open a terminal. Type `sudo update-grub` and check if that helps you, don't forget to reply!

Comment: it throws /usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `/cow'

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason they don't want you running linux in a Virtual Machine(VM)? Setting up a Linux VM in Windows using VirtualBox or VMware player is pretty easy compared with what you've already been through. In VMWare player, pick shared networkibg, so that your Linux VM gets it's own IP address. This way any web-site you put up will be visible by all the machines on your network (if you configure things this way).

For VirtualBox the setting you want is under:

```
Machine
    Settings
        Network
```

Then choose:

```
Adapter 1
    Shared network
        and pick your network adapter.
```

This even works if you're on a laptop connected wirelessly. But if you've connected many USB networking adapters, then you'll see all of them. However the active network adapter(s) should be on top (it was for me when I made this change right now)

You could add a USB adapter and specifically use it for the virtual machine if you have problems with the above. But how to tell Windows not to use it is beyond me.

Do NOT use NAT as your networking type (instead of Shared Mode) unless you don't mind only being able to browse to your websites from the computer running the VM. Under VirtualBox I just tested this and I didn't even have to reboot the Linux VM.

This command (issued from a terminal window).

```
ifconfig
```

will show you the IP address of the Linux VM.

```
jmitchel@MontyPython:/var/log$ ifconfig
enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    **inet 10.0.0.108**  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
    inet6 fe80::baae:edff:fe3f:b639  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether b8:ae:ed:3f:b6:39  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 2523  bytes 288155 (288.1 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 2689  bytes 624000 (624.0 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The formatting is a little off, but you can see the IP address with **'s around it.

Hope this helps,

Jason M.